# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bar'

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I need a instance of a class that is shared among nodes (singleton).
Problem is I can't call the methods of it.
Here is the problem isolated:

```
import bpy
from ... base_types.node import AnimationNode


class Singleton:

    def __call__(self):
        return self

    def bar(self):
        print("bar")


class Foo(bpy.types.Node, AnimationNode):
    bl_idname = "an_Foo"
    bl_label = "Foo"

    singleton = None

    def create(self):
        self.singleton = Singleton()

    def execute(self):
        self.singleton.bar()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\clankill3r\AppData\Roaming\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\animation_nodes\execution\main_execution_unit.py", line 38, in executeUnit
>       exec(self.executeCodeObject, self.executionData, self.executionData)   File "execution: 'NodeTree'", line 4, in
>      File "C:\Users\clankill3r\AppData\Roaming\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\animation_nodes\nodes\serial\foo.py",
>   line 24, in execute
>       self.singleton.bar() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bar'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only store some specific property types on the nodes directly.
These here: https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_release/bpy.props.html

If you want to access the same variable from multiple nodes you can simply create the instance outside of the node like in this example:

```
import bpy
from ... base_types.node import AnimationNode

class Singleton:

    def __call__(self):
        return self

    def bar(self):
        print("bar")

# store the instance in the module namespace
singleton = Singleton()

class Foo(bpy.types.Node, AnimationNode):
    bl_idname = "an_Foo"
    bl_label = "Foo"

    singleton = None

    def create(self):
        pass

    def execute(self):
        # don't use 'self' because the singleton is in the module namespace
        singleton.bar()
```

Comment: Thanks man, you're a huge help speeding up my development :)